# SQL Search if contains keyword random

Tags: php, mysql

I working on my search function and I have an Issue

My query:

```
$query          = " SELECT p.ID, p.post_title
                    FROM $posts p
                    LEFT JOIN $postmeta pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = '_sku')
                    WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
                    AND (
                        p.ID LIKE '%$keywords%' OR
                        p.post_title LIKE '%$keywords%' OR
                        IF(pm.meta_value IS NULL, 0, pm.meta_value LIKE '%$keywords%')
                        )
                    ORDER BY p.post_title";
```

In the column post_title I have a value like **Remy Martin XO**
Now you can search on Remy or Martin or Remy Matin and there are results.
But if you search on Martin Remy there are no results.

What I tried so far:

I changed the query and replaced the LIKE to CONTAINS but now I have no results on any search

```
$query          = " SELECT p.ID, p.post_title
                    FROM $posts p
                    LEFT JOIN $postmeta pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key = '_sku')
                    WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
                    AND (
                        p.ID LIKE '%$keywords%' OR
                    --> CONTAINS(p.post_title, '$keywords') <-- OR
                        IF(pm.meta_value IS NULL, 0, pm.meta_value LIKE '%$keywords%')
                        )
                    ORDER BY p.post_title";
```

Who can help me with this?

Comment: You need to use a full-text index if you want to do this kind of searching.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `CONTAINS()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your line with this line. Hopefully it will work.

```
CONTAINS(p.post_title, '$keywords',1) > 0
```

If it is my SQL then use `INSTR(str,substr)`. You can search this Syntex you will get lots of example.